# Python error : unsupported operand between instances of int and list

Tags: python, list

I was trying to add elements, but it always shows this error

```
def maximum_toys(cost, N, K):
        count = 0
        sum = 0
        for i in range(0,N,1):
            cost.sort(reverse = False)
        for i in range(0, N, 1):
            x=int(cost[i])
            # Check if we can buy ith toy or not
            if (sum+x <= K):
                sum = sum + x
                # Increment the count variable
                count += 1
            return count

# Driver Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    K =input().split()
    cost = []

    cost = input().split()
    N = len(cost)

    print(maximum_toys(cost, N, K))
```

Comment: Despite the indentation, the code is actually accepted. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

In Python, the `input` function returns a string; when you split it you get a list of strings. It seems like you want them to be lists of ints; you can do this like this: `cost =[int(i) for i in input().split()]`

The error culprit is here:

```
if (sum+x <= K):
```

where `sum+x` is an integer, but K is a list; did you perhaps mean `sum(K)`; FWIW since **sum** is a reserved word in Python I wouldn't use it as a variable, preferring something like `total` instead.

That said, I think you have some other issues also:

```
        for i in range(0,N,1):
            cost.sort(reverse = False)
```

It is just going to sort the list over and over (only need to do it once); also FYI that's the same as `range(N)` since the `0` and `1` are the default values.

---

I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
def maximum_toys(prices, wallet):
  count = 0
  prices.sort(reverse = False)

  for price in prices:
    if (wallet-price > 0):
      wallet -= price
      count += 1
  return count

# Driver Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    K =float(input("Wallet: "))
    toy_prices = [int(i) for i in input("Toy Prices (eg. '1 2 3 4'): ").split()]

    print("total toys purchased:", maximum_toys(prices, K))
```